# javascript , jquery Object [object Date] has no method 'format'

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the following code, but currently experiencing format has no method. It is completely working off another site because i used the exact same code for reference. Now i am unsure why it didnt work for my site when i copied it over.. Can anyone help me out?>

```
 var TodayDate = new Date();
    TodayDate.setDate(TodayDate.getDate());

    var PastDate = new Date();
    PastDate.setDate(PastDate.getDate() - 30);

    StoreHeavyTraffic = 0;
    StoreRoadWork = 0;
    StoreVehicleBreakdown = 0;
    StoreAccident = 0;
    StoreObstacle = 0;

    var PD = Date.parse(PastDate.format("d MMM yyyy"));
    var TD = Date.parse(TodayDate.format("d MMM yyyy"));
```

Comment: Native date object doesn't have a method called format. You might be missing a library at your site.

Comment: it seems a momentjs method http://momentjs.com/

Comment: yes i know that , the other reference source i copied from has jquery.js, jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is a native javascript object and it doesn't have a `format` method. The method you are trying to use looks like [`moment`'s format method](http://momentjs.com/) which also cannot be called on native Date objects

Comment: it works completely fine from the reference site i copied from, and its the exact same coding.. Not sure what i am missing out.. can you help me out?

Comment: What's the reference site?

Comment: its abit complicated. It can only run from my office network.. I have the same exact source on my machine but it cannot run due to proxy error. would you mind teamviewing me for awhile?

Comment: You must not have downloaded all of the javascript, and if they extended the native `Date` object, it's worth looking into doing it the right way using a library like momentjs (many examples of what you are trying to accomplish on moment's homepage).

Comment: I dont think its moment.. I have ran the debug console for many hours but to no avail, as well as comparing the reference scripts.I am trying to keep the code as close as possible to the reference site. 
Would you mind teamviewing me for a short while? help me greatly appreicated